# Name the property illustrated by $-ab + ab = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Name the property illustrated by $-ab + ab = 0$

I do not know any of the properties in algebra, if possible can you give me some definitions?

Comment: There should be a list in your textbook.

Comment: Are you missing some parentheses in this equation?  Depending on how you read this, it simply mean the additive inverse of $ab$ is the additive inverse of $ab$, or that $ab$ has an additive inverse.  Throw in some parentheses and it might be something more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression looks like it is defined in some ring. Rings are algebraic structures with addition and multiplication (which we will denote with $+$ and $\cdot$ respectively) and following laws must hold:

> **1)** $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)\quad$   *(associativity of addition)*
>
> **2)** there exists $0$ such that: $a + 0 = 0 + a = a\quad$ *(neutral element for addition)*
>
> **3)** for all $a$ there is $-a$ such that: $a + (-a) = -a + a = 0\quad$ *(additive inverse)*
>
> **4)** $a + b = b + a\quad$ *(commutativity of addition)*
>
> ---
>
> **5)** $(ab)c = a(bc)\quad $ *(associativity of multiplication)*
>
> ---
>
> **6)** $a(b+c) = ab + ac\quad $ *(left distributivity)*
>
> **7)** $(a+b)c = ac + bc\quad $ *(right distributivity)*

*(Notice that we usually don't write $\cdot$, i.e. instead of $a\cdot b$ we write just $ab$.)*

Sometimes rings have additional property:

> **8)** there exists $1$ such that $1\cdot a = a\cdot 1 = a\quad$ *(multiplicative neutral)*

and such rings are called unital. Or they could satisfy:

> **9)** $ab=ba\quad$ *(commutativity of multiplication)*

in which case we call them commutative rings.

Example of unital commutative ring you are familiar is $(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$, ring of integers. Other examples of unital commutative rings include ring of rational numbers ($\mathbb Q$), ring of real numbers ($\mathbb R$) and ring of complex numbers ($\mathbb C$). The latter examples are not just rings, they are actually *fields*, i.e. they satisfy additional axiom:

> **10)** for all $a\neq 0$, there exists $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1} = a^{-1}a = 1\quad$ *(multiplicative inverse)*

*(Note: enumeration of axioms is not in order usually presented when talking about fields.)*

Your expression lacks some parentheses, but most likely it should read as: $$-(ab) + ab = 0$$ and you will find that this always holds in any ring by axiom 3).

Answer (score 1):

your looking dor the Additive Inverse: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse